# python subprocess popen nohup and return code

Tags: python, subprocess, nohup

I have the following code:

```
    argpass = ['nohup']
    argpass.append('/path/to/script')

    log_output_err = open(log_file,'a+')
    out = subprocess.Popen(argpass,
                       stdout = log_output_err,
                       stderr = log_output_err)

    #if the script fails I need to have some logic here...
```

I just wonder how I can get the return code of the /path/to/script.

Maybe I just need to insert the logic in /path/to/script, any thoughts?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

The `subprocess.Popen` object has a `returncode` attribute you can access:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode

You could also look at using the `check_call` convenience function:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call

It will only return if the return code was zero; otherwise, it will raise a `CalledProcessError` (from which you may read the `returncode` attribute).

Your example, with stdout and stderr pointing back at the invoking Python script rather than a log file:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> argpass = ['echo']
>>> argpass.append('hello world')
>>> # I reroute to PIPE because I don't have a logfile
>>> log_output_err = subprocess.PIPE 
>>> out = subprocess.Popen(argpass,
               stdout = log_output_err,
               stderr = log_output_err)
>>> output,error = out.communicate()
>>> print output
hello world

>>> # Check if child process has terminated. 
>>> # If it has finished, will return returncode attribute.
>>> # Otherwise, it returns None
>>> out.poll()
0
>>> # Or we can read the returncode attribute directly:
>>> out.returncode # Direct
0
>>>
```

If your process will take a long time to finish, the `returncode` value might not be set when you go to check it. If the value of the `returncode` is `None` that means your child process has not yet terminated. You can stop execution of your script until after the child process has terminated with the `.wait()` method.

Comment: `subprocess.PIPE` works but insted when you give a opened file `out` returns as `None` so I wont able to capture the error message :     `with open('myfile', "w") as outfile:
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                             stdout = outfile,
                             stderr = outfile)` @chucksmash